# Designing custom unsubscribe page in Mautic

Tags: mautic

How do I configure a custom unsubscribe page in mautic, I quite like how listmonk unsubscribe page looks like

[image]

I want a similar page in mautic.

1. When user clicks on the unsubscribe link on the email they should be taken to a page where they will see a button "Unsubscribe" they have to click that button to unsubscribe. In mautic, just clicking the link in email unsubscribes you right away. But I want an explicit user action from that page
2. I also want a check box that says "Also unsubscribe from all future emails", which will basically blocklist this user so no future marketing emails are sent

I have read a lot of documentation and I am not able to figure out how to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is called a Preference Centre in Mautic. You will create a landing page and then select the option to make it a preference centre.

We have a feature coming to add the blocks to the new GrapesJS builder but until then you can use the tokens to position the relevant blocks.

Check out the docs here: https://docs.mautic.org/en/contacts/preference-center

https://docs.mautic.org/en/contacts/preference-center/customize-preference-center

Note: Screenshots are the legacy builder - we are in the process of updating the docs and replatforming but the variables are the same.